How does your denomination refute the various claims that God is a liar?
A recent question asked for a natural theology answer to this question. I am however more interested in a denominational answer with the valid reasoning, theology, doctrine, etc. of that denomination.
During my research to answer the question I found some specific arguments for the case that "God lied"
I'm interested in Eastern-Orthodox, Catholic, Angelcan, Any Protestant denomination, as well as any other denominations such as Jehovah's witness, Mormons, and the many others I am unaware of.
Please clearly state which denominational opinion you are refuting from, if that denomination uses more than Scripture as a valid source of information please state that fact clearly.
For example: "From the position of the Eastern Orthodox church, we use sources of scripture, the writings of saints, the apocryphal texts, as well as the church tradition as valid sources..."

Example 1 - 1 Kings 22:19-23 (NKJV)

19 Then Micaiah said, “Therefore hear the word of the Lord: I saw the Lord sitting on His throne, and all the host of heaven standing by, on His right hand and on His left. 20 And the Lord said, ‘Who will persuade Ahab to go up, that he may fall at Ramoth Gilead?’ So one spoke in this manner, and another spoke in that manner. 21 Then a spirit came forward and stood before the Lord, and said, ‘I will persuade him.’ 22 The Lord said to him, ‘In what way?’ So he said, ‘I will go out and be a lying spirit in the mouth of all his prophets.’ And the Lord said, ‘You shall persuade him, and also prevail. Go out and do so.’ 23 Therefore look! The Lord has put a lying spirit in the mouth of all these prophets of yours, and the Lord has declared disaster against you.”

This is also found in 2 Chronicles 18:18-23 as well
The basic argument here is the same as the legal argument of "Call to action" makes the person who commanded or asked for a crime to be committed guilty of the crime.

Example 2 - 2 Thessalonians 2:11-12 combined with 2 Peter 3:9

And for this reason God will send them strong delusion, that they should believe the lie, that they all may be condemned who did not believe the truth but had pleasure in unrighteousness.


The Lord is not slack concerning His promise, as some count slackness, but is longsuffering toward us, not willing that any should perish but that all should come to repentance.

Strong delusion implies that God is messing around with free will as well as this seems to contradict the other scripture.

Example 3 - Genesis 2:17 and Genesis 5:5
Similar but not exactly the same as this other question

but of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat, for in the day that you eat of it you shall surely die.”


So all the days that Adam lived were nine hundred and thirty years; and he died.


Example 4 - Jewish scholar Yael Shemesh - Genesis 18:12-13

"In one case we even find God twisting the truth in order to preserve amicable relations between Abraham and Sarah and to prevent Abraham’s feelings from being hurt. Upon overhearing the prediction that she was about to become pregnant, Sarah laughs, “Now that I am withered, am I to have enjoyment—with my husband so old?” (Gen. 18:12); God, however, quotes her in Abraham’s hearing as having said, “Shall I in truth bear a child, old as I am?” (Gen. 18:13), making no reference to Abraham’s inadequacy. This episode was used by the Sages of the Talmud as a proof-text showing that it is permitted to deviate from the strict line of truth in order to establish peace (BT Yeb. 65b; BT B.M. 87a)." (Yael Shemesh, Lies by Prophets and Other Lies in the Hebrew Bible, 2. Lies in the Bible  (paper|Bar-Ilan University), p. 4.)


If it is too vague, I can divide the question into 7 specific ones that are each denomination specific.

Non-denominational Evangelical here.
The lying spirit of 1 Kings 22 is sent into the mouths of prophets who have no desire to utter the truth into the ears of a king (Ahab) who has no desire to hear the truth.
This is an example of a "giving over" principle which is seen throughout Scripture and particularly pointed to by Paul in Romans:

And even as they did not like to retain God in their knowledge, God gave them over to a reprobate mind, to do those things which are not convenient; - Romans 1:28

God neither lies nor meddles with free will.  He desires all to come repentance but does not force them.  As He alone perceives and rightly judges the deceitful and wicked human heart, He alone sees when the point of no return has been reached.  Let the one who is currently resisting Him tremble...you might be on the raggedy edge.
Strong delusion is sent to those who disbelieve the truth in favor of the pleasures of unrighteousness:

And for this reason God will send them strong delusion, that they should believe the lie, that they all may be condemned who did not believe the truth but had pleasure in unrighteousness.

Pharaoh hardened his own heart a number of times before God finally honored that desire and finalized the hardening.  Had God foreseen that Pharaoh would truly repent and believe, He would have honored that instead.  Election is according to the foreknowledge of God.
As Evil Snack has answered, Adam did die that day as He became separated from God, who is the only source of life. He, as we, are dead in trespasses and sin.  Mercifully, God sustained his physical life (and ours as well) to provide an opportunity to repent and believe.
Both Abraham and Sarah were physically inadequate and this is made clear in the text, not glossed over:

Therefore Sarah laughed within herself, saying, After I am waxed old shall I have pleasure, my lord being old also? 
And the LORD said unto Abraham, Wherefore did Sarah laugh, saying, Shall I of a surety bear a child, which am old?

God is light and in Him is no darkness at all.

It seems like the obvious flaw of most of the "God is lying" things is found by assuming God is like us. He does not act upon his creatures in the same way that creatures act upon each other. He does not act upon them at all. What He does, rather, is speak creatures into being from out of nothing, continuously and eternally. It is not the literal case that God first creates something and then acts upon it (which is how, I think, we all tend to picture the matter). There is simply God creating reality out of nothing in one eternal act. --- Nice answer Thank you :)

Church of Christ member here. I do not speak for the church officially, and I cannot quote anybody who does, because the Churches of Christ reject that any man now alive is so authorized. However each of us can tell you what he or she believes, based on what the Bible says.
The principle I find in the divine record is that God does not lie to people who want to know the truth; but if a person defiantly turns away from the truth, God leaves that person to be prey for liars.
As for Adam, he did die when he ate that fruit, because in doing so he became separated from God by his sin. When the Scriptures speak of death they do not always speak of physical death. This is not unique to the Church of Christ; most Christian churches hold to the same belief.

Thank you for the answer. I appreciate your refutation of the "die" paradox as the spiritual type and not the physical kind. I'm honestly surprised that many people have not answered already. I expect that they would use a similar phrase to refute that specific one as well. :)

In the Reformed Protestant denominations, they predominantly refute claims that God is a liar by showing the truth of God, as revealed in God's word, and in the Person of Jesus Christ, who was, in the beginning, the Word of God. There are also scholarly books / articles written, but my answer is designed to show that what God has, himself, revealed to us through his word, evidences that God is Truth personified (especially in the person of Jesus Christ, who said he was the Way, the Truth, and the Life so, if he lied, God lied as he was God incarnate.)
Right from the beginning of the Bible, God's truth is challenged by "the father of lies" (as Jesus identified that evil one in John 8:44-45). The whole Bible details this war between the truth of God and the lies of the evil one who deceives the whole world of mankind. It follows from that, that all people who listen to the whispers of one "in whom there is no truth" will claim that the God of the Bible is a liar. Some go so far as to claim that the satanic one is pure truth, and must be believed. They decry the God of the Bible as a liar (unsurprisingly).
A few sample Bible texts to support belief in the God who reveals himself to humanity, right from Eden till his new heavens and earth is established:
God is not a man that he should lie. Numbers 23:29;  The Glory of Israel does not lie. 1 Samuel 15:29; Let God be [found] true, though every man a liar. Romans 3:4; But the cowardly, the unbelieving, the vile, the murders... and all liars - their place will be in the fiery lake of burning sulphur. This is the second death. ...Outside [heaven] are... the idolaters and everyone who loves and practices a lie. Revelation 21:8 & 22:15.
Now, if God was a liar, why would he put outside of Eden and keep out of his Heaven all liars?
A point that helps to explain why some people decry God is stated in the Old Testament here. King David had experientially found God to be utterly dependable and true, saying of him:

"With the merciful thou wilt shew thyself merciful, and with the
upright man thou wilt shew thyself upright. With the pure thou wilt
shew thyself pure; and with the froward [crooked, liars] thou wilt
shew thyself unsavoury. And the afflicted people thou wilt save: but
thine eyes are upon the haughty, that thou mayest bring them down." 2
Samuel 22:26-28 A.V.

This helps to explain why some people find God distasteful - not to their liking - appearing to be a God who lies. And there is voluminous written evidence throughout history of God being accused of being irrational, undependable, deceiving, contrary, and lying. Today is no different. It was always thus.
This means that there is no need to try to individually refute the examples given in the details of the question. The quote from 2 Samuel 22:26-28 covers all of them. Further, for every example shown to be misunderstood, those who haughtily seek to find fault with God will simply come up with other examples of how they perceive the God of the Bible to be, not knowing that they are walking in the gloom of satanic deception, because they are prideful - haughty. "God needs to answer to us!" is their motto, when God has no need to answer to anybody. He just leaves the proud to get on in their way of pride (until the Day of Judgment). Humility is what God looks for in people. He knows their hearts. That is involved in how (or whether) he draws them to himself, in love.

So the answer is kind of a "those who do not want to trust God, will distrust him" ?

@Wyrsa. No, it says those who are prideful will not find God to be as do those who are humble before him. Many who have not trusted God later on find God to be utterly trustworthy. It depends on their heart-condition. God is judge of all and knows those who belong to him, and those whom he will free from satanic deception. We cannot judge.
